# How can i add send email button to account home page

Tags: list-view

Hope everyone doing well.  I am unable to find a solution on  Google.  I am trying to add a button (email send )on the account home page. please check the image to clear  the question

[image: want to add send email button]

Comment: You'll have to provide some more detail on what you've tried. Also, your question says 'please check the image', but there is no image.

Comment: I upload the image but  I don't know where it go.I want to add a new button (send email button ) to the account home page, not the detail page. I mean the page where all accounts are listed.

Comment: please check image

Comment: see Idea: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqfqAAC

Comment: still not helpful